# 'Client' object does not support the asynchronous context manager protocol in discord py v2

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, pycord

So, my bot was working well and fine until i had to deploy it in a host server.
Before this, i was still using the old bot methods, (the one that uses client.run(token)), but with a host server, i had to update it to the new form of loops (using asyncio and asyncio.run). It works well on the server, but dont work in my pc / local host.

I use the same code in both of them and only get an error on my local pc.
The code:

```
import asyncio
import discord
import os
from decouple import config
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(intents=discord.Intents.all(), command_prefix=".")
token = config("TOKEN")

async def load_extensions():
    for filename in os.listdir("./commands/events"):
        if filename.endswith(".py") and not filename.startswith("__"):
            await client.load_extension(f"commands.events.{filename[:-3]}")

    for filename in os.listdir("./commands/text_commands"):
        if filename.endswith(".py") and not filename.startswith("__"):
            await client.load_extension(f"commands.text_commands.{filename[:-3]}")

async def main():
    async with client:
        await load_extensions()
        await client.start(token)

asyncio.run(main())
```

The error in vscode: 'Bot' object does not support the asynchronous context manager protocol (line 20 in main async with client, line 24 in module asyncio.run(main())
I mean, if its the same code, it should work on both, but only works on the host server.

Edit:

[The actual error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hH48.png)

Also yes, my discord module is updated and i think its updated in the server too.

Comment: That screenshot shows a different error message from what you posted, that would only have come from different code than what you posted. (Also, are you using pycord or discord.py? Those are two different things.)

Answer (score 0):

Are the versions of module in your local system same as that with host server?(most likely cause)
Do share a screenshot of error , if lines of other modules are present in the error.
According to [this api reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.intents)
,there have been some changes in newer versions.